# Converting Class to Functional: Passing down state objects

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently using the [React + Material UI + Firebase](https://github.com/Phoqe/react-material-ui-firebase) template found on the Material UI document for a school project. Right now, I am trying to convert [App.js](https://github.com/Phoqe/react-material-ui-firebase/blob/master/src/components/App/App.js) over to using hooks. So far I have this, but I need help with the DialogHost component in which we pass down various dialogs. Here is a simplified version of the file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import DialogHost from './components/DialogHost';

function App() {
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(false)
  const [ready, setReady] = useState(false)
  const [dialog, setDialog] = useState({
    isOpenSignUp: false,
    isOpenSignIn: false,
    isOpenSignOut: false,
    isOpenSetting: false
  });

  const handleOpenDialog =  e  => {
    setDialog({...dialog,[e.target.name]: true});
  }

  const handleCloseDialog =  e  => {
    setDialog({...dialog,[e.target.name]: false});
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {ready &&
        <>
      <Navbar 
        signedIn={signedIn}
        onOpenDialog={handleOpenDialog}
        onCloseDialog={handleCloseDialog}
      /> 

      <DialogHost 
        signedIn={signedIn}
        // HOW TO CONVERT THESE DIALOGS (which is currently setting state  as signUpDialog: {open: true}) USING HOOKS?
        dialogs={
          {
            signUpDialog: {
              dialogProps: {
                open: signUpDialog.open,

                onClose: (callback) => {
                  this.closeDialog('signUpDialog');

                  if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
                    callback();
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            signInDialog: {
                  dialogProps: {
                    open: signInDialog.open,

                    onClose: (callback) => {
                      this.closeDialog('signInDialog');

                      if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
                        callback();
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
          }
        }
      />
    </>
  }
</ThemeProvider>


 );
}

export default App;
```

If I'm not mistaken, I think the context api would work here, but just would like to know with this current implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will work for the above code:

```
<DialogHost
    signedIn={signedIn}
    dialogs={{
        signUpDialog: {
            dialogProps: {
                open: dialog.isOpenSignUp,
                onClose: callback => {
                    handleCloseDialog("isOpenSignUp")
                    if (callback && typeof callback === "function") {
                        callback()
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        signInDialog: {
            dialogProps: {
                open: dialog.isOpenSignIn,
                onClose: callback => {
                    handleCloseDialog("isOpenSignIn")
                    if (callback && typeof callback === "function") {
                        callback()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }}
```

If you want to use a Context in a Functional Component you have to use [useContext Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) instead of Context.Consumer.